# Symbolic solution of linear systems in Java

Tags: java, math, symbolic-math

Consider a typical system of equations like the following:

```
p x + 3 y = 0
2 x + q y = 0
```

Where p and q are symbols (they do not take values). I want to solve the system with a symbolic expression, for x and y, containing p and q.

I tried question [How to Solve Equations with Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431885/how-to-solve-equations-with-java) and [How to Solve algebraic equations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9154990/java-how-to-solve-algebraic-equations), but these are interested only in finding the arithmetic (not symbolic) values of x and y.

I'd like to know if there are Java packages that can handle symbolic calculation to solve such systems.

Comment: Well, Mathematica costs $1500...

Comment: Take a look at SymJa: https://code.google.com/p/symja

Comment: @irreputable I know how to solve this in Matlab but I need Java specifically.

Comment: @pents90 I'll check that thank you.

Answer (score 0):

See another question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574949/is-there-something-like-sympy-for-java, its responses point to useful symbolic math libraries usable in Java.
You could find useful pointers also among the [JAS](http://krum.rz.uni-mannheim.de/jas/related.html) related resources page.

Comment: I have also found JAS but its documentation is not clear on how it deals with symbols. I have not tried all the other proposals in there yet.

Comment: I checked the proposed solutions mentioned in the question you suggested. However: JSCL link did not work, symja seems to be more lika a tool than a reusable library. There was no API nor source code to download. And sympy and jpython implies usage of Python which I am not familiar with.