# How can an equation be solved using Java?

Tags: java

I would like to calculate a formula like x+3-5*4=5 and to find the x, in java. How could i do that?

In the given example the x would be 22.I need something like an interpreter or something...i have tried with PostFixed forms and other but that ones dont work with variables...need help

Comment: Certainly postfix works with variables. That's what the JVM does.

Comment: I edited the title to clarify the question. Now it should me marked as duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431885/how-to-solve-equations-with-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try any of these:

- [Commons Math](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/linear.html)
- [JAMA (Java Matrix Package)](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/)