# Java Runtime Compiling within scope

Tags: java, compilation, runtime, classloader, abstract-syntax-tree

Is it possible to recompile java code within a class at runtime?

Example:

```
package com.main;

public class Main {

public static int a = 5;
public static int b = 10;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int c = func(a, b);

    compile("int func(int a, int b) { return a * b; }");

    int d = func(a, b); 
}

static int func(int a, int b) {
    return a + b;
}
}
```

So in this example the compile function would overwrite an existing method.

My program takes in marks/points which the uni gives to their students and since most subjects have a different method for calculating the overall gained scores the user should be able to change those individually.

Is it possible to do something like this without using an AST(abstract syntax tree) or having to compile a new class file which has to inherit certain methods?

Comment: What would be wrong with just having one compiled method which contains logic to discriminate between different use cases?

Comment: I support Tims question, forthemore you could use an equiation solving library (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431885/how-to-solve-equations-with-java)

Comment: @TimothyTruckle Right idea, right first name :-)

Comment: That the methods for measuring your performance within a semester are so diverse. Some subjects will have a homework, some don't, some have tests during the semester, some don't, etc. And some will combine these and have a function for calculating the score you achieved, like:

Comment: 0.25 * (Test1 + Test2) + 0.75 * Exam

Comment: Then use an expression library. Or the built-in JavaScript.

Comment: See example: [IDEONE](https://ideone.com/S3rugh)

Comment: How did I not know about this? Thanks man, appreciated :) Now I just have to match the fields with the input values.